# How To Pass Component Pointer From QML To C++?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

What is the easiest way to pass a component pointer created in a QML file to C++? From [Qt Documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-interactqmlfromcpp.html) explanations we could take the QML file root object and then search for our component `objectName`. But it's hard to keep sync the components `objectName` in both C++ codes and QML codes:

<sub>Just for Copy/Paste: [qml_pass_objectName_example](https://github.com/gccore/examples/tree/master/sub_examples/qml_pass_objectName_example/source)</sub>

```cpp
auto const root = engine.rootObjects();
if(!root.empty())
{
    auto const obj = root.first()->findChild<test_item*>("testItem");
    if(obj)
    {
        c.setup_test(obj);
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << "Couldn't Cast";
    }
}
else
{
    qDebug() << "Empty";
}
```

I tried to pass the component from QML code on `Component.onCompleted`:

###### main.qml  <sub>(for copy/paste: [qml_pass_id_example/main.qml](https://github.com/gccore/examples/blob/master/sub_examples/qml_pass_id_example/source/main.qml#L12))</sub>

```cpp
TestItem
{
        id: testItemId;
        Component.onCompleted: controller.setup_test(testItemId);
}
```

###### main.cpp  <sub>(for copy/paste: [qml_pass_id_example/main.cpp](https://github.com/gccore/examples/blob/master/sub_examples/qml_pass_id_example/source/main.cpp#L45))</sub>

```cpp
class controller : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
  public slots:
    Q_INVOKABLE void setup_test(test_item* item)
    {
        item->f();
    }
};
#include "main.moc"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    controller c;
    qmlRegisterType<test_item>("qml.pass.id", 1, 0, "TestItem");
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("controller", &c);
    engine.load("qrc:/qml_pass_id_example/main.qml");
    return app.exec();
}
```

And I think this is much simpler than using `objectName`, but I couldn't find any related documentation about passing the component's ID to C++ functions. So my questions:

1. What is the easiest way to passing the QML component pointer to C++?
2. Is passing the QML component ID as the component C++ type pointer to the C++ function valid?

---

- Qt: <kbd>6.2.0</kbd> and <kbd>5.15.2</kbd>.
- Compiler: <kbd>GCC 11.1.0</kbd> and <kbd>MSVC 2019</kbd>.
- Platforms: <kbd>MS Windows</kbd> and <kbd>GNU/Linux</kbd>

Comment: For clarity, the example given is _not_ a Component pointer, but a pointer to an object. You can pass `QQmlComponent *` just fine, which will allow you to instantiate the Component from C++ as often as you want (a la `Repeater`), but that's not what you are seem to be looking after in this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The easy thing is debatable since it depends on the definition of what is easy or difficult for each case so I will not answer this question since it falls outside of SO.
2. Yes, it is valid to export any QML object to C ++. The id is the reference to the object so you are not passing the name "testItemId" but you are passing a `test_item` object that has as identifier "testItemId".

Note: It is recommended not to expose any QML object to C ++ (or do it for a minimum time) since its life cycle is managed by QML so it could be eliminated at any moment causing you to access pointers that no longer have associated objects. .

Comment: Could you please add a reference to the documentations about passing the component's ID from QML to C++?

Comment: @GhasemRamezani See https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-data.html#qobject-derived-types

Comment: Yes, you are probably better of connecting a C++ signal on the QML side in this example